# Использование для многостраничного сайта одного файла php или несколько html?

Tags: php, html, html5

возник такой вопрос есть сайт с меню (при нажатии на кнопки меню открывается новая страница сайта с определённой информацией). В данной версии сайта  я передаю нажатие кнопки с помощью функции get в одном файле php и в зависимости от значения переменной отрисовываю ту или иную страницу. Значение переменной проверяются в  этом же файле. Вопрос заключается в том, целесообразно ли разбить код одного файла php на несколько файлов html?

P.S. ниже часть кода моего файла php. Вопрос задаю с целью максимально оптимизировать работу сайта

```
 <div class="roud">
       <input type="button" class="r1" value="Главная" onclick=" location.href='my.php'">
       <input type="button" class="r1" value="Услуги" onclick=" location.href='my.php?x=Услуги'">
       <input type="button" class="r1" value="Техническое задание" onclick=" location.href='my.php?x=Техническое задание'">
       <input type="button" class="r1" value="Контакты" onclick=" location.href='my.php?x=Контакты'">
       <input type="button" class="r1" value="О нас" onclick=" location.href='my.php?x=О нас'">
       <input type="image" class="r01" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" src="../images/viber1.png">   
       <input type="image" class="r01" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" src="../images/WhatsApp1.png">
       <input type="image" class="r01" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" src="../images/telegram1.png">

    </div>


<?php
if (isset($_GET["x"])) {
    $retur=$_GET["x"];
       if ($retur=="Услуги"){
          echo "
           ...
          ";
        } else {
            if ($retur=="Техническое задание"){
              echo "
              ...
               ";
            } else {
                if ($retur=="Контакты"){
                  echo "
                    ...
                   ";
                } else {
                    if ($retur=="О нас"){
                       echo "
                       ...
                       ";
                    }
                }
            }
        }


} else {
echo "
...
";
}
```

Comment: Я так понял вам нужен php роутинг, собственно про него и почитайте

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тоже хотел предложить PHP Routing, но @Dantessss немного опередил меня. Сам этому учился с помощью этой статьи: http://maxsite.org/page/routing

Также рекомендую прочитать о работе сервера Apache и его файла `.htaccess`, очень доходчиво про этот файл рассказывается в этой статье на Хабре: https://habr.com/post/154643/